# Number of observations falling in a given criteria if mean and standard deviation are given.

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

This is a question from an entrance test.  I was trying to solve it but now,  i am stuck in it. Question is :

> If a data set is approximately normal with sample mean of 75 and standard deviation of 5, how many observations fall with 75 + 
>   or - 5?

The answer options were available in percentage.

Comment: Hint: The key is knowing that the distribution is normal. For the specific solution see, for instance:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule

Comment: Thank you.  I find out 68% as answer.

Comment: Well done. I've written it as an answer so that you can accept it (there is a green button), if you think it's appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

The key is knowing that the distribution is normal.

For the specific solution see, for instance: [68–95–99.7 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule).